# Gradle throws NoClassDefFoundError for dependencies with implementation keyword

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I'm using Intellij Idea, with `gradlew` version 6.8.

Whenever I point `implementation` keyword for dependencies in `build.gradle` - I get(example with `gson` dependency) this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
        at com.epam.adnocove.search.job.EmailVerifier.<clinit>(EmailVerifier.java:19)
        at com.epam.adnocove.search.job.UserIndexPipeline.<clinit>(UserIndexPipeline.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 2 more
```

my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.epam.adnocove'
version '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Program'
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

If I put `compile` instead of `implementation` - everything works as expected. But what if I don't want transitive dependency. Why gradle doesn't put my dependency to my jar?

Comment: `build.gradle` is a [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) script, while `compile` is an (obsolete) collection of dependencies included into `implementation`. The is why in your script `configurations.compile` iterates over an empty set. Use `configurations.implementation` to add your implementation dependencies to the fat jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by default build along with java plugin only - Gradle doesn't pack dependencies into jar - therefore we get an exception.

The solution:
we can use [fat jars](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_packaging)(by separate task), or use java [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:building_java_applications) which will create OS-specific startup applications which can run built jar.